# Get the last sum instead of loop 0 to n in javascript (with some simple calculate)

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm coding a small game. Users need experience to reach next level.

From level 0 to level 1, it cost 5000xp

From level 1 to level 2, it cost 5500xp

From level 2 to level 3, it cost 6000xp
...

Now I want to calculate the exp for an specific level, maybe 232

I can get the result by the following code

```
const calculateXP = (level) => {
  let xpNeeded;
  let accountXp = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < level; i++) {
    xpNeeded = 5000 + (i * 500);
    accountXp += xpNeeded;
  }
  return accountXp;
};
```

The result is `14558000`

It's an ugly and long solution. Is there any shorter solution? without loop from 0 to N (the level that I want to calculate exp)?

Comment: Level 1 need `5000`, 500 for an next level, How about 5000 + (232 - 1) * 500?

Comment: @VanTho oops, I copy pasted wrong one, updated my question.

Comment: @jameswargo Show us what you've tried, please.

Comment: @Daedalus-ReinstateMonica edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an solution (1)

```
let level = 232;
let exp = 5000 + (level - 1) * 5000 + (level * (level - 1) / 2) * 500;
console.log(exp);
```

Or an shorter version (I've checked and it works with all level i've tested from 0 to 500000 :v)

`let exp = 250 * (x * x + 19*x)`

Refered from sumFrom function in [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117166/sum-all-numbers-in-a-range)

But how to get level from exp, check this out

```
const getLevelByExp = (exp) => {
    // x^2 + 19x = exp/500
    let x1, x2;
    let x, y, z, delta;
    x = 1;
    y = 19;
    z = -(exp / 250);
    delta = (y * y - 4 * x * z)
    x1 = (-y - Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2 * x);
    x2 = (-y + Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2 * x);
    if (x1 > 0) return x1;
    // x2 always bigger than 0
    if (x2 > 0) return x2;
}
```

I've decoded it from (1)

You can test my function by the following code

```
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    let exp = calculateXP(i);
    let decoded = getLevelByExp(exp);
    console.log('Level: ' + i, 'Exp: ' + exp, 'Decoded: ' + decoded);
}
```

The output level is the same

Comment: This code also work with level 0 and level 1

Comment: Yeah and I've edited your question, my English is bad but I don't want you to receive down vote anymore T.T

Comment: thanks for edit :), don't want to bother you too much, but do you know how to get level based on xp?

Comment: I've edited my answer. When finding a way to solve your problem, I also found an shorter way to get `exp`